# Facing problem in using Post call with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am integrating an api that belongs to POST method. And I am using below code to Consume the post api.

```
 public void attemptLogin(final String email, final String password) {
    WebApi api = mRetrofit.create(WebApi.class);

    Call<LoginModel> call = api.attemptLogin("eng", email, password);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginModel> call, Response<LoginModel> response) {
            String name = "abdul";
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginModel> call, Throwable t) {
            String name = "abdul";
        }
    });
}
```

Below is the definition of **attemptLogin()** method which is defined in WebApi interface.

```
  @FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/Login")
Call<LoginModel> attemptLogin(
        @Field("language") String language,
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password
);
```

Below is the instantiation of Retrofit Block in a constructor.

```
   public WebServiceManager() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppConstants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
}
```

Here is the thing I am getting callback of **onResponse()** of retrofit but it is giving me error code 500. In this case, I checked out errorBody of response object below is the error i got

**is not a valid display name in myserver.domain**

Any help why I am getting this error

Comment: Is the AppConstants.BASE_URL is good ?

Comment: add your response as well.

Comment: @Vodet Yes, I am using url something similar like this "https://abc-dev.net/"

Comment: @KaranKhurana I am not getting any response. Response object the body variable is null. Am I right or you were asking something else?

Comment: is your url https ?

Comment: @KaranKhurana yes it is HTTPS

Comment: With Volley it's easier  "https://developer.android.com/training/volley"

Comment: actually 500 response code means this is due to server, so first try with Postman. it will give exact cause of problem

Comment: actually I have tried the same api over swagger and postman. In both cases api is working

Comment: Can you post the screenshots of Swagger or Postman client? I don't think you're passing the values in a format which server is expecting from Android. Hence, you're getting 500 error response.